# List<Ttype> to List<TInterface> in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, interface

*I wanted to do something like co-variance in C# but I dont have here any inheritance .*

I have this code :

```
public interface IBirthday
{
   void Dance ();
}


public class Birthday:IBirthday
{
 public void Dance()
    {}
 }


void Main()
{
  List<Birthday> l= new List<Birthday>();
  List<IBirthday> d = l; //<--- How can I accomplish that ? 
}
```

HOw can I make this work ? (besides iterating and build manually ( linq or loop))

```
List<IBirthday> d = list of birthdays ?
```

does iterating/linq is the only choice?

Comment: Did you try [`Cast`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406.aspx)?

Comment: You can't and shouldn't, it's not type-safe precisely because of the lack of covariance. You should be able to do `IEnumerable<IBirthday> d = l;` though.

Comment: Why do you want a `List<IBirthday>` ?  That's the  linchpin here and the use-cases seem small.

Comment: @millimoose - consider posting that as an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not *possible* to assign a `List<Birthday>` to a `List<IBirthday>` without creating a brand new list (it can be hidden from you, but it *must* happen somewhere).

If what you were trying to do were possible then what would happen when someone did:

```
public class UnBirthday : IBirthday { ... }

d.Add(new UnBirthday());
```

Well, it's a `List<IBirthday>`, so it thinks that it's able to add the new item.  But the underlying list is actually a `List<Birthday>`, and you can't add an `UnBirthday` to that list.  Given the choice between allowing this and just crashing at runtime, C# made the decision (correctly, in my opinion) of just not allowing it in the first place.

The only way to utilize generic argument covariance, which is what you're trying to do, is to assign it to something that can only read information out, and never put information in.  One example of this is `IEnumerable<T>`.  Every single `Birthday` is an `IBirthday`, and there's no way for `IEnumerable` to be given an `IBirthday` that's not a `Birthday`, so saying:

```
List<Birthday> l= new List<Birthday>();
IEnumerable<IBirthday> d = l;
```

works just fine.

Comment: It would be possible to construct a `ReadOnlyListWrapper<T,U> where U:T` which would wrap an `IList<U>` and implement `IList<T>`, and report itself as read-only.  Such a thing would not be able to store `T`'s in the original list, but would present a "live" view of the list and would not require copying it.

Comment: @supercat That would be what I cover in my last paragragh, it's just another example of a covariant interface.  (You could use `IReadOnlyList` in .NET 4.5 and it would work for `List` or an array in just the same way as `IEnumerable`.)

Comment: My point was that even though there isn't any built-in class to do so, one could easily write a wrapper class that would allow an `IList<U>` to be used as an `IList<T>` (allowing individual items to be read, "live", by index), and not just `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: @supercat Yep, I provided one example interface, it's not the only one.  `IReadOnlyList` is another, and you could make your own if you wanted.  As long as you're only reading information you can do it.

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
d = l.Cast<IBirthday>.ToList();
```

Comment: This is not assigning a new view onto the existing list, it's just creating an entirely new list.  That may or may not be semantically what you want.

Comment: I wrote no iterating (niether linq)

Comment: @Servy True, I didn't consider this.  I'm not sure how you'd get around this though

Comment: @TheEvilPenguin You wouldn't.  That's the answer.  It's not *possible* without building a new list.